# Create Chat-thread endpoint not working on Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've been using the following end-point for some time and it has stopped working `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/chatThreads`.

Body :

```
{
"rootMessage": {
    "body": {
        "contentType": 2,
        "content": "Hello world"
    }
}
```

The response is :

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'chatThreads'.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "8cd24e52-f0eb-4203-bc63-0de4f358c863",
        "date": "2020-01-24T10:53:02"
    }
}
```

When I tried to navigate to the documentation page ([Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/channel-post-chatthreads?view=graph-rest-beta)) it gives me a 404. Has something happened this end-point? Ensured both my `team-id` and `channel-id` are correct.

Link to graph explorer to reproduce - [Graph-Explorer, Preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview).

Have also tried changing from beta to v1.0 but to no avail.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem. How did you solve this error?

Comment: @Jose Microsoft updated the endpoint, see the marked as correct answer below; it solved it for me, although I did have to update the content type and accept permissions too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this has been replaced by "/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages", as per [Create chatMessage in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

It also looks like the "contentType" payload might have changed - in the page I linked it show "html" versus an integer like "2". See [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta#properties).

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that earlier and forgot about the permissions... The content type has changed too. Guess they have to remove chatThreads from the explorer.

Comment: sounds like it!